# Rethrowing an error causes vue warning in jest test

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I've got a vue application which exists of a page component and a nested child component, which makes a async post-request. If the request is failing, an error is thrown, which is propagated to the top component (`Page.vue`). This top component handles all errors of its child with the `errorCaptured`-Lifecycle hook. Here is an working example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-surdfb?file=src/App.vue)

The mechanism is working fine and no warning is displayed for my app. However, I want to **test my child component isolated** with jest and vue-test-utils. Therefore, I made a test:

```js
import { mount } from "@vue/test-utils";
import Child from "./Child";

jest.mock("./api", () => ({
  createSomething: jest.fn(),
}));

it("creation is erroneous", async () => {
  const wrapper = mount(Child);

  createSomething.mockImplementation(() => {
    throw new Error("error");
  });

  let createAction = wrapper.find("[data-test-create]");
  await createAction.trigger("click");
});
```

However, because the **error is rethrown and never catched by the parent component**, there is always a console log statement in my test output:

```
  console.warn
    [Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of native event handler 
      at <Child ref="VTU_COMPONENT" > 
      at <VTUROOT>
```

How can i solve this? I tried to wrap `await createAction.trigger("click");` with `try/catch` but its not working. Do I need to mock the errorCaptured lifecycle of my parent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to set a no-op [`app.config.errorHandler`](https://vuejs.org/api/application.html#app-config-errorhandler) via the [`global.config`](https://test-utils.vuejs.org/api/#global-config) mounting option:

```js
const wrapper = mount(Child, {
  global: {
    config: {
      errorHandler(err) { /* ignore */ },
    },
  },
})
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-jest-ignore-uncaught-error?file=tests%2Funit%2FChild.spec.js)